# How can I write to multiple sql files, having a .net console application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code in which its function to perform is: Write a text to a notepad which works for me but I want it to write to a .sql file which works if the file is blank, but when it has content I the text appears in another language. I would like to know what I could do to solve my problem, also if the text that I put in my file is in the first part of the page.
[this appears in the sql when I run my console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9jRH.png)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
 {
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Proyectos\Prueba", "*.sql", 
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    string filesname = null;
    foreach(string file in filePaths)
    {
        filesname = Path.GetFileName(file);
        char[] Mychar = { '.', 's', 'q', 'l' };
        string variable = filesname.TrimEnd(Mychar);
        string text = "USE prueba\nGO \nSET ANSI_NULLS ON \nGO \nSET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
        \nGO \nIF OBJECT_ID('" + variable + "', 'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC " + variable + 
         ";  \nGO \n ";
        //Escoger la ruta
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(file, text);
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(file));
            sb.AppendLine(text);
            //Sirve para abrir el archivo y agrega el string especificado
            File.AppendAllText(file, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    
}
 }
}
```

Comment: No need for `ReadAllText` or the StringBuilder since you're using `AppendAllText`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine ok its correct but in the same way I get the error